# How is this nonexistent WordPress directory accessible?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how a WordPress site running BuddyPress (not even sure if BP is relevant here) successfully links to something like `example.com/my-directory/` when there is no such directory as `/my-directory/` within the WordPress setup of `example.com`. There are scripts running from within that directory and I can see in the website UI code and at execution that it's being linked to correctly. However, there isn't even a symlink or an htaccess or an alias in the PHP code throughout the entire site or on the server that points to where that directory's code really resides. Can anyone point me in the right direction on figuring this out?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

Comment: They don't necessarily have to exist. You can just spoof the URL as if it did exist.

Comment: It's called [REST](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html) (or a RESTful API) - the Internet lies to you, URLs are not the same thing as the filesystem in any way. You think Stack Overflow *really* has a directory per question?

Comment: I get that, CD001. What I don't know how to do is figure out where the REST is taking over. This is a self-contained site that isn't going "outside" for anything.

Comment: Is there anything shown on that URL? Or is it just showing a different page (which is also accessible by a different URL).

Comment: There is content showing at that URL. Server-side PHP also seems to be running out of that URL.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it was a Page post type with that slug defined and pointing to a specific template. Had to dig through the database to find it. Thanks to all who responded.